# MySQL via PHP 8.3.2 echoing keys instead of values

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code I wrote awhile ago that no longer works but used to:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'Title', 'Author', 'Author (Last, First)', 'Year Published', 'Publisher' FROM bb_2_4_23 ORDER BY " . $_SESSION["order"] . " LIMIT ". $number_per_page . " OFFSET " . $_SESSION["start"];

//mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='book'>";
    echo "<a href= 'book.php?title=". $row["Title"] . "'><i>". $row["Title"] . "</a></i> <br>by " . $row["Author"]. "<br>";
    echo $row["Publisher"]. " " . $row["Year Published"] . "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
} else {
  echo "<p>No books could be found.</p>";
}
```

The output looks like:

Title
by Author
Publisher Year Published

Title
by Author
Publisher Year Published

Title
by Author
Publisher Year Published

Title
by Author
Publisher Year Published

Which is to say that the $row keys are echoed in place of values. Has something changed with the way PHP works with associative arrays & mysql? The documentation I've looked at suggests the code should work, if I understand it.

I am using php 8.3.2 on a Mac mini (M1, 2020) that I've just installed php on via homebrew. The $sql works fine inside myPhpAdmin.

Comment: `SELECT 'Title'` will always return 'Title' as the value, using something like `SELECT title` would be the value from the column.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the single quotes in your SELECT statement.